# Multiple codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) matching were found

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, keychain, provisioning-profile

```
Code Sign error: Multiple matching codesigning identities found: Multiple codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) matching “iPhone Developer: Coders (4B4R89J5KK43GU33E64I4347VZ)” were found
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Unit Test Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 8.0'
```

I am unable to test the app on the device.

I also imported the `.developerprofile` file from my teammate, and was able to upload the app to app store, but cannot test app on device.

In `keychain` all the certificates are valid.

I tried to deleting `iOS Provisioning Profiles`.

I also refreshed my setting using these steps

- In Xcode Preferences

  - >  In Accounts click on your Apple ID
  - > Click View Details
  - >  Click on your projects Provisioning Profile
  - >  Click refresh button bottom left

Clean and build again, but still facing the same issue not running on device.

Comment: Did you make sure your "Unit Test" target has the same code signing profile as the normal target and project, inside the *Build Settings* ? (Along the top row of buttons and to the left of Build Settings is a drop down list, if you click on it, it shows Project and Two Targets, your normal app binary target and also the unit test target, I recall having a similar problem in the past, not sure if this helps)

Answer (score 13):

Make sure you don't have duplicate Certificates in Keychain Access in your Mac.
To check this open Keychain Access and within "My Certificates" check that you don't have duplicate certificates, if this is your case, remove the duplicates.

Comment: Some duplicate revoked and expired certificates were causing this problem for me. Removed them all and it solved it.

Comment: Shouldn't there actually be a better way to fix this?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the solution was the automatic "iOS Developer" option (With Xcode 6.2)

[image: Build Settings]

And on the second "Build Settings":

[image: Build Settings]

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem a few months ago and just ran into it again just now.  Last time I fixed it by refreshing my account under Preferences.  It did not work this time even after removing/adding all the accounts and clear all xcode related keychain items.

Finally I changed the Provisioning Profile from "Automatic" to a specific Profile which worked.