# IOS app can't launch after 2 days of inactivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I created an app and tested in my iPhone and iPad. Its working fine. That means no issues while running. But I can't launch my app after 2 or 3 days of inactivity. When I try to launch, splash screen will come and  suddenly it will go to background (I don't know it is crashed or not). If I clear it from background and take it from background at that time also has same issue. The only way to test it again is reinstalling the app. I want to share two errors coming in xcode, I don't know it is the reason for this issue.

1. While I try to reinstall, that time one error is coming in xcode, thats is something like your certificate expired or your device clock is not set properly. That time I refresh my account details then I can reinstall the app.
2. My app is using ARC. When I check arc convertion in xcode through

> edit->convert->To objective-C ARC

That time one error is coming like

> "Code Sign error: Multiple matching codesigning identities found:
>   Multiple codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key
>   pairs) matching “iPhone Developer""

But I can install the app in device and it will work without any error.

Comment: have you bough developer certificate?

Comment: problem ins in your apple certificate may be expired just check ..

Comment: Have you checked your device's logs when the app crashes? Have you retrieved crash logs?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519703/multiple-codesigning-identities-i-e-certificate-and-private-key-pairs-matchin

Comment: @Tj3n , ya developer certificate I have